# php array to json array (using sendgird)

Tags: php, arrays, json, sendgrid

I would like to use a php array in this example rather than have to hard code the array. How would I use a php to replace this json example?

Here the working code with the json array:

```
$json_string = array(

  'to' => array(
    'example1@sendgrid.com', 'example2@sendgrid.com'
  ),
  'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

But I need to replace the 'to' values with my own php array. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$myEmails[] = array('emailOne@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com');
$json_string = array(

  'to' => $myEmails, /// DOES NOT WORK
  'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

**What code for the json could I use to add my own php array values here?** In short I am trying to send multiple emails using sendgrid but I thought this might work but its not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the square braces [] after $myEmails, and everything should work:

```
<?php 
  $myEmails = array('emailOne@gmail.com','email2@gmail.com');
  $json_string = array(
    'to' => $myEmails, /// DOES NOT WORK
    'category' => 'test_category'
  );
  var_dump($json_string);
?>
```

Comment: That did it! :) Funny thing is when I typed this email I forgot to add them. Then I made an edit and added them. Good thing I caught that one. Too bad I didn't forget them when i was coding. hehe. Ok I will mark this right in 8 minutes when I can. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good thing you caught and fixed it when you did or I would have been puzzling over the code!  :)  I must have seen it right after you edited.